# How to automate conversion of images

Tags: bash, imagemagick-convert

I can convert an image like this:

```
convert -resize 50% foo.jpg foo_50.jpg
```

How can I automate such a command to convert all the images in a folder?

You can assume every image has `.jpg` extension.

A solution easily adaptable to automate the conversion of all the images inside the subdirectories of the working directory is preferable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a for loop with pattern expansion:

```
for img in */*.jpg ; do
    convert -resize 50% "$img" "${img%.jpg}"_50.jpg
done
```

`${variable%pattern}` removes the pattern from the right side of the $variable.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is exactly what I was looking for, but I couldn't get the pattern expansion right. Your explanation in the last sentence helped me too, to understand what I was doing wrong.

Comment: This only finds files in subdirectories, and only one level deep - or am I missing some `shopt` setting here?

Comment: `shopt -s globstar; for img in **/*.jpg` works for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `find -exec`:

```
find -type f -name '*.jpg' -exec \
bash -c 'convert -resize 50% "$0" "${0%.jpg}"_50.jpg' {} \;
```

`find -type f -name '*.jpg'` finds all `.jpg` files (including those in subdirectories) and hands it to the command after `-exec`, where it can be referenced using `{}`.

Because we want to use parameter expansion, we can't use `-exec convert -resize` directly; we have to call `bash -c` and supply `{}` as a positional parameter to it (`$0` inside the command). `\;` marks the end of the `-exec` command.

Comment: One quick question: Will it not cause a recursion, when the newly generated files will also be `.jpg`? Does `find` buffer entire list first, or does it find the files in batches? It seems to work with file count of ~200 for me.

Comment: @anishsane It doesn't seem to, but I'd have to dig into the documentation to show you a quote to ascertain the exact behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this (less elegant) one-liner using ls+awk:

```
ls *.jpg | awk -F '.' '{print "convert -resize 50% "$0" "$1"_50.jpg"}' | sh
```

this assumes that all the .jpg files are in the current directory. before running this, try to remove the `| sh` and see what is printed on the screen.